# Warning: compiled but with compilation errors trigger in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, warnings, compiled

```
ALTER TABLE student ADD gpa NUMBER;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "USER36401"."GETGPA" AFTER
  DELETE OR
  INSERT OR
  UPDATE ON grade_report FOR EACH row DECLARE totalqp NUMBER :=0;

  totalgpa      NUMBER :=0;
  totalcreds    NUMBER :=0;
  prevqp        NUMBER :=0;
  prevgpa       NUMBER :=0;
  prevcreds     NUMBER :=0;
  incomingqp    NUMBER :=0;
  incominggpa   NUMBER :=0;
  incomingcreds NUMBER :=0;
  temp          NUMBER :=0;
  BEGIN
    CASE
    WHEN updating THEN
      UPDATE student SET student.gpa = NVL(student.gpa,0);
      SELECT student.gpa
      INTO temp
      FROM student
      WHERE student.student_number = :NEW.student_Number;
      IF temp                      <1 THEN
        totalqp                   := temp;
        SELECT DISTINCT DECODE(:NEW.GRADE,'A','4','B','3','C','2','D','1','F','0')
        INTO temp
        FROM student,
          section,
          course
        WHERE :NEW.student_number   = student.student_number
        AND :NEW.section_identifier = section.section_identifier
        AND section.course_number   = course.course_number;
        UPDATE student
        SET student.gpa              = temp
        WHERE student.student_number = :NEW.student_number;
      ELSE
        prevgpa := temp;
        SELECT student.total_credit_hours
        INTO temp
        FROM student
        WHERE student.student_number = :NEW.student_number;

        prevcreds := temp;
        SELECT DISTINCT course.credit_hours
        INTO temp
        FROM course,
          section
        WHERE course.course_number    = section.course_number
        AND section.section_identifier= :NEW.section_identifier;
        --current
        SELECT DISTINCT course.credit_hours
        INTO temp
        FROM course,
          section
        WHERE course.course_number    = section.course_number
        AND section.section_identifier= :NEW.section_identifier;

        incomingcreds := temp;
        prevcreds     := prevcreds - incomingcreds;
        prevqp        := prevgpa   * prevcreds;
        --total quality points before add
        SELECT DECODE(:NEW.GRADE,'A','4','B','3','C','2','D','1','F','0')
        INTO temp
        FROM student,
          section,
          course
        WHERE :NEW.student_number   = student.student_number
        AND :NEW.section_identifier = section.section_identifier
        AND section.course_number   = course.course_number;

        incominggpa := temp;
        --gpa being added before quality points
        SELECT DISTINCT course.credit_hours
        INTO temp
        FROM course,
          section
        WHERE course.course_number    = section.course_number
        AND section.section_identifier= :NEW.section_identifier;

        incomingqp := incominggpa*incomingcreds;
        totalqp    := prevqp     + incomingqp;
        totalcreds := prevcreds  + incomingcreds;
        totalgpa   := totalqp    / totalcreds;
        UPDATE student
        SET gpa                      = totalgpa
        WHERE student.student_number = :NEW.student_number;
      END IF;
    WHEN DELETING then
    Select * from student where student.student_number = :NEW.student_number;
    END CASE;
  END;
```

the goal is for the trigger to do "something [not implemented yet]" on delete.

when i compile, it says compile, but warning with errors. i'm burned out as hell for finals week, and this is the last project. i can't find the error where it's at, i'm sure it's something syntactical that i'm not spotting. any help is greatly appreciated.

edit:also, i understand this is probably the most ineffecient way to implement what i'm trying to do. but i'm basing my code entirely off of what the professor has listed we can use in the powerpoint slides in class. and quite frankly, this is for my minor specialization, and i'm a senior, so i don't really care. i just need it to work.

edit3:

from the compile trigger script: ALTER TABLE student succeeded.
Warning: execution completed with warning
TRIGGER "USER36401"."GETGPA" Compiled.

```
insert into grade_report values ('17','112','B');
select * from student;
insert into grade_report values ('17','119','C');
select * from student;
insert into grade_report values ('8','85','A');
select * from student;
insert into grade_report values ('8','92','A');
select * from student;
insert into grade_report values ('8','102','B');
select * from student;
insert into grade_report values ('8','135','A');
```

returns error: "Error starting at line 1 in command:
insert into grade_report values ('17','112','B')
Error at Command Line:1 Column:12
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'USER36401.GETGPA' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger."

Comment: A description of the error(s) would help, as well as the line on which the error occurs.

Comment: what does `show errors` give you?

Answer (score 0):

You last select statement (in the 'delete' branch of the case), doesnt' have an INTO clause. Also, you use `SELECT *`, while you need to specify the exact field to select into the variable.

You do the same thing in the other branch of the case, why not look at that?

Comment: i added a basic "into" clause into my select statment, and still error. i suspect that it is in the syntax somewhere in my case statement. it i remove the case parts, and execute just in the first case, it coompiles and behaves properly. i modified to read `WHEN DELETING then
      SELECT * into temp from student where student.student_number = :OLD.student_number;
    END CASE;`

Comment: That's another error. You cannot `SELECT * INTO variable`. You will need to specify the column to select.